# Does using RestSharp client require RestSharp on the server?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

My server exposes a JSON WebAPI that is not built with .NET.
Can I still use a RestSharp client to GET the JSON payload from the WebAPI?

Thanx

Comment: Yup, JSON is language, device, protocol agnostic. Its just a lighweight object notation which can be shared whatever the weather.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the only thing the client cares about is the format of the data, not how it's produced.